# Blacklist the "default" and "value" tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-blacklist-request

[default](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default) should be blocked; it was used in completely unrelated questions about a default value, such as:

- [Setting default image style to 'original image' in formatter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31616/setting-default-image-style-to-original-image-in-formatter)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/disabled-checkbox-in-fapi
- [Default values help](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/drupal-7-default-values) (The question is about a default image.)
- [Default date field values like "today +10 hours 30 minutes"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/default-date-field-values-like-today-10-hours-30-minutes)

[value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/value) was used in unrelated questions, such as the following ones:

- [How to display image instead of a value in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/how-to-display-image-instead-of-a-value-in-drupal-7)
- [Token replacement for list keys](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19343/token-replacement-for-list-keys)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-to-get-the-currently-displayed-value-from-a-select-list
- [How to list and store the value of hidden exposed filter of several views for anonymous user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14012/how-to-list-and-store-the-value-of-hidden-exposed-filter-of-several-views-for-an)
- [Output view field as link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12769/output-view-field-as-link)

Both the tags are too generic to be really helpful; the answer for a question doesn't change, if one of those tags is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like neither tag is used right now and I'm not seeing strong support for blacklisting here.

If the tags keep coming back and can't be controlled with simple retagging, we can revisit this.